# Change spring bean properties at configuration time

Tags: java, spring, properties

In a spring servlet xml file, I'm using `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` to regularly fire a set of triggers.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref local="AwesomeTrigger" />
            <ref local="GreatTrigger" />
            <ref local="FantasticTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The issue is that in different environments, I don't want certain triggers firing. Is there a way to include some sort of configuration or variable defined either in my build.properties for the environment or in a spring custom context properties file that assists the bean xml to determine which triggers should be included in the list? That way, for example, `AwesomeTrigger` would be called in development but not qa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a factory bean that returns a list of triggers based on a property

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <bean class="com.yourcompany.FactoryBeanThatReturnsAListOfTriggers">
            <property name="triggerNames" value="${some.property}" />
        </bean>

    </property>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your.properties" />
```

**Reference:**

- [the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

What I've done :

I overrode the Trigger bean to add a property enabled.

And after I overrode SchedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers and I only set the enabled triggers.

You just need to use these new beans in your xml files and the enabled in your properties file.

Ex :

```
public void setTriggers(Trigger[] triggers) {
        ArrayList<Trigger> triggersToSchedule = new ArrayList<Trigger>();

        for(Trigger trigger : triggers){
            if(trigger instanceof SimpleTriggerBeanEnabler){
                if(((SimpleTriggerBeanEnabler)(trigger)).isEnabled()){
                    triggersToSchedule.add(trigger);
                }
            }
            else{
                triggersToSchedule.add(trigger);
            }
        }


        super.setTriggers(triggersToSchedule.toArray(new Trigger[triggersToSchedule.size()]));
    }
```